# Jest testing dynamic import with jest-next-dynamic

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, next.js, enzyme

I am trying to test dynamic import in nextjs version 10.2.3, i tried using jest-next-dynamic library which avoid throwing error

> TypeError: require.resolveWeak

but when i debug the component in jest test case i get below output and cannot get real component that should be loaded

```
 <ForwardRef(LoadableComponent) .../>
```

My test case

```
it('should render Image component from next/Image', () => {
  await preloadAll();
  defaultProps = getDefaultProps(imgSrcFromAssetsLocation);
  const ContainerImage = shallow(<ContainerImage { ...defaultProps } />);
  console.log(ContainerImage.debug());
  expect(ContainerImage.prop('layout')).toEqual('responsive');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

After some time i figured out we need to wait for dynamic element to load in test case using waitFor or something similar, documentation of "jest-next-dynamic" does not include this, i found this from below github repo
[github repo with example](https://github.com/fu4303/portfolio-sergiodxa/blob/1f768512cdfbe8ba97f611f90ce29251658c478a/content/articles/testing-in-next-dynamic-imports.mdx)

Comment: this approach mostly works, but `waitForElement` is deprecated with `react-testing-library` - I adapted it to use `waitFor` from `@testing-library/react`:

`import { render, waitFor } from "@testing-library/react";

    test('renders with correct props', async () => {
      await preloadAll()

      const { getByRole } = render(<SomeComponent {...testProps} />);

      await waitFor(() => {
        const component = getByRole('textbox')
        expect(component).toBeInTheDocument();
      })
  })
`

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue while executing jest tests despite the modules loading well at runtime.

I had a custom package consumed as:

```
const MyReactComponent = dynamic(import('@mynamespace/myModule/MyReactComponent'))
```

My solution was to modify the way my custom module would export the component from:

```
module.exports = MyReactComponent
```

to:

```
exports.MyReactComponent = MyReactComponent;
exports["default"] = MyReactComponent;
```

Since I am using rollupJs to build, I could achieve this change by simply exporting const as well as default.
changing from:

```
const MyReactComponent: React.FC<...> = ...

export default MyReactComponent;
```

to

```
export const MyReactComponent: React.FC<...> = ...

export default MyReactComponent;
```

This allowed me to run tests and execute the package.
I hope this helps someone :)